# RenderTargetBitmap works fine on Windows 8.1, but not on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm making a universal app. In my app I need to use RenderTargetBitmap to convert an Image and a TextBlock over the image into a JPEG photo.
On the Windows 8.1 project, everything works as expected, but not on the Windows Phone 8.1 one. Could you help me with that?
Thank you.

My code is as follows:

```
async Task SaveVisualElementToFile(FrameworkElement element, StorageFile file, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
    {
        var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(element, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

        using(IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var encoder = await
                BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
            byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                 BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                                 (uint)imageWidth, (uint)imageHeight,
                                 96, 96, bytes);

            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

It is throwing the error in the line
    byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();
The error is:
    "The specified buffer index is not within the buffer capacity"

I am calling the method with this:

```
    var file = await KnownFolders.CameraRoll.CreateFileAsync("abc.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    Image image = new Image();
    image.Source = bitmapImage;
    image.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;

    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.FontSize = bitmapImage.PixelHeight / 15;
    tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    tb.Text = "abcdefg";
    tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
    tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.Children.Add(image);
    grid.Children.Add(tb);

    renderBmpGrid.Children.Add(grid); //renderBmpGrid is a Grid of
                                      //the visual tree
    await SaveVisualElementToFile(grid, file, bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);
```

Comment: The width and height passed to `RenderAsync(...)` are multiplied by [`RawPixelsPerViewPixel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.rawpixelsperviewpixel.aspx). And so `renderTargetBitmap.Width` is not the same as `imageWidth`, and it's the one you should be passing to `SetPixelData(...)` (the same goes for height). Also, you may want to have an upper bound of width/height because of memory/image limits (not sure what they are, though).

Comment: Thank you! But the exception is thrown before I create the BitmapEncoder, so this is unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: Yes, I can't say this is causing the problem, but it seemed relevant to what you're doing, so I mentioned it. Have you tried with a small image (like 500x500 px)? Does it still give you an error? Also, have you tried debugging it - going through the code line by line and checking if all the variables have correct/expected values? I tried but I couldn't reproduce that error.

Comment: Yes, I tried al this, and I discovered that both píxels.Capacity and pixels.Length return 0, but I don't know why.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that's what's causing the error... but I have no idea why they're 0. How is renderBmpGrid defined?

Comment: `<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <GridView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1301" Height="666"/>
        <Button x:Name="processBtn" Content="Procesar todas las fotos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="642,700,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.039,0.011" Height="39" Click="Button_Click"/>

        <Grid x:Name="renderBmpGrid" Opacity="0">
            
        </Grid>
    </Grid>`