# how to draw text on picture and save it on windows phone c# app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am using windows phone 8.1 c# app visual studio 2015

‍‍`Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage` is not working on windows phone 8.1

now here is my code from android and i need do the same in windows phone c#:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
canvas.drawText("Testing...", 10, 10, paint);
```

WriteableBitmap.render is not working. i know WriteableBitmap.render can solve my problem.  windows phone 8.1 c#   WriteableBitmap.render is not found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write Text On An Image in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826921/write-text-on-an-image-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage not working on windows phone 8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 - Write text over WriteableBitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486278/windows-phone-8-1-write-text-over-writeablebitmap)

Comment: is there a simple code  as this on android canvas.drawText("text...", 10, 10, paint);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This samples uses the Lumia Imaging sdk and Win2D

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598529.aspx

https://github.com/Microsoft/Lumia-imaging-sdk/tree/master/Samples/LumiaImagingSDKWin2DDemo

Answer (score 0):

See an example from msdn: [WindowsPhone: Write Text on Image control](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-Write-Text-on-2fa9c4cf)

Comment: you url does not contain any code and i tried  RenderTargetBitmap. ithink windows phone is not capable of editing hi res images,  windows phone is more focused on ui and text-boxes